# Avoiding a fetch in a custom setter

Tags: core-data

I have two entities, Item and Category. Each item has one category, and a category can have 0-many items.

I have a special category, the misc category. I denote this with a boolean property, isMisc, so category.isMisc=YES.

When I delete a category, I want to reassign any of its items to the "misc" category. So I wrote the following custom setter for item:

```
- (void)setCategory:(Category *)category
{
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"category"];
    if (category == nil) {
        category = [Database theMiscCategory];
    }
    [self setPrimitiveValue:category forKey:@"category"];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"category"];
}
```

The problem is, [Database theMiscCategory] performs a fetch, which I believe is discouraged. Is there another way to do this?

I have looked at just letting item.category = nil, but this introduces enough complications in other areas of the code that I'd much rather have a "misc" category.

Comment: Couldn't you fetch the "misc" category once when your program starts, and always use that instance ? Or do you work with multiple managed object contexts?

Comment: Hey @MartinR, that's a good idea. The Database class is currently just a bunch of static methods. I've thought about making it a singleton, in which case I could do that fetch when the singleton is initialized.  Could I make a static member? Or am I going to have to get off my butt and create the singleton?

Comment: There are probably many possible solutions. As long as you work only with a single context, you could keep your `theMiscCategory` method, but change it so that it caches the result in a static variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create or fetch the "misc" category object once in your program, e.g. after creating the managed object context. Then your custom setter method can always use this instance.

If you work with several managed object contexts, then you would have to create one object for each context.